# How to split a word into letters and put them into an unordered list/set?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a simple anagram checker that compares two user inputs and prints whether the pair is an anagram or not.

Figured this would be a good way to go about it:

-Ask for user input1 and user input 2

-split input1 and input2 into individual letters

-put input1 letters into an unordered set and input2 letters into another unordered set.

-`if (unordered set 1 == unordered set 2)`
    the pair is an anagram.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to split the inputs into individual letters and put each of them into their own unordered list/set.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()

{

    std::cout << "Hey there! enter a pair of words and tell you if they're an anagram or not." << endl;

    std::cout << "Enter first word: ";  
    std::string firstword{};
    std::cin >> firstword;

    std::cout << "Enter second word: ";
    std::string secondword{};
    std::cin >> secondword;

    //split firstword into letters
    //put letters into set1

    //split secondword into letters
    //put letters into set2

    //if (set1 == set2)
        //the pair is an anagram

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: those strings, `firstword` and `secondword` already *are* a collection of letters.

Comment: I'd be inclined to just sort the letters of each word into alphabetical order and check whether the resulting words are the same,. Unordered set does a lot of wheel spinning that you don't need for something as straightforward as this.

Comment: Your idea doesn't work because `unordered_set{'a', 'b'} == unordered_set{'a', 'a', 'b'}` but ab is not an anagram of aab.

Comment: If you don't want to sort characters, you could instead build a histogram and then compare that.  While this has linear time complexity, (as opposed to N.logN for sorting) it could actually be less efficient in practice, given the average length of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can go about doing this. The way I chose to go about it is by first sorting each string, iterating through each of the strings and comparing the index of one string with the index of the other. In C++, each string is made up of characters, or chars, so you can access individual pieces of a string by their index.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string firstWord;
    string secondWord;
    bool isAnagram;

    cout << "Hello! Enter the first word: ";
    cin >> firstWord;
    sort(firstWord.begin(), firstWord.end());

    cout << "Enter the second word: ";
    cin >> secondWord;
    sort(secondWord.begin(), secondWord.end());

    if(firstWord.length() == secondWord.length())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < firstWord.length(); i++)
        {
            if(firstWord[i] == secondWord[i])
            {
                isAnagram = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isAnagram = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        isAnagram = false;
    }

    if(isAnagram)
    {
        cout << "It's an anagram!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "It's not an anagram.\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A few side notes: I included **using namespace std;** at the top of my program. This is generally considered bad practice as it pulls the entire std namespace into the global namespace and can lead to name collisions. However, it works well for testing purposes. I also included the **algorithm** preprocessor directive, which contains the **sort()** function that I used to sort the strings.

Comment: That algorithm would consider the strings `"!!"` and `"B"` anagrams of each other (Assuming ASCII, of course).

Comment: Good catch. Edited.

Comment: Note that everything from `if(firstWord.length() == secondWord.length())` to the end of its `else` clause can be replaced by `isAnagram = firstWord == secondWord;`. <g> +1.

Comment: @TuckerAlan thank you for the solution. As a c++ newbie it took me a few mins to understand it though as I didn't understand what the sort function did. So here's a newbie's explanation of your solution that might help out other newbies that land on this page:

Comment: Ask for a pair of words as user inputs. Use sort() to rearrange the chars(here, letters) in ascending order. Now use an if statement to compare the length of both the sorted words. If they are equal, use a for loop to iterate through each character and check if they are the same. As @PeteBecker points out, a simpler way is to avoid for loop altogether and ask the program to check if one sorted word is equal to the other sorted word.

Answer (score 1):

If given words are anagrams then they must be a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)s of the same letter set.

```
#include <algorithm>

bool are_anagrams(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.size() != rhs.size())
    {
        return false;
    }

    return std::is_permutation(lhs.cbegin(), lhs.cend(), rhs.cbegin());
}
```

The [std::is_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation) is a free function from `<algorithm>` header that checks if provided iterators point to the permutations of the same set.

Refering to the question "how to split string into letters and put it into the set", you can use the `std::set` constructor to achive this goal.

```
std::string word = "foo";
auto start = word.cbegin();
auto end = word.cend();
std::set<char> letters{start, end};
```

The `std::set` constructors takes as a paramters a pair of iterators and uses them to construct the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a string exactly like over a vector. The elements are just the letters (as char).